# Dynamic prefix routing in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm currently facing an issue with the prefix routing. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right for the routing, can you help me?

Here is the context: My website has 2 front and 1 back. All views will kind of be similar, just some section will disappear.

Urls should be like this:

```
localhost/admin
localhost/front1
localhost/front2
```

When I tried to go to localhost/front1/login, I have this error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {brand}/login]. (View: F:\StockageUnit2\Developpement\projets\billetterie\resources\views\auth\login.blade

What am I doing wrong ?

And how do I differentiate which route I'm using on my template for the href ?

How I am supposed to redirect depending on  the prefix as href is determined by the route name?

I read the documentation and found no clues about it...

**app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot() 
{ 
    parent::boot(); 
    Route::bind('brand', function ($value) { 
        return Brand::where('slug', $value)->first() ?? abort(404); 
    }); 
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use \App\Brand;

Route::get('/' , 'HomeController@index')->name('main');

/*Back*/
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin'
], function () {
    Route::get('/' , 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
    AuthRoutes();
});

/*Front*/
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{brand}'
], function () {
    Route::get('/' , 'BrandsLandingController@index')->name('main_landing');
    AuthRoutes();
});

function AuthRoutes()
{
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
    Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
    Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
    Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
}
```

**route:list**

```
|        | GET|HEAD | /                              | main                | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | 
|        | GET|HEAD | admin                          | admin.home          | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index                             | |        
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/email/resend             | verification.resend | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@resend                | web,auth,throttle:
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/email/verify             | verification.notice | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@show                  | web,|
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/email/verify/{id}        | verification.verify | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@verify                | web,auth,signed,e:6,1 |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/login                    | login               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,|
|        | POST     | admin/login                    |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,|
|        | POST     | admin/logout                   | logout              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | |
|        | POST     | admin/password/email           | password.email      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,|
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/password/reset           | password.request    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,|
|        | POST     | admin/password/reset           | password.update     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,|
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/password/reset/{token}   | password.reset      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,|
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/register                 | register            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,|
|        | POST     | admin/register                 |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,|
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                       |                     | Closure                                                                | api,|
|        | GET|HEAD | {brand}                        | main_landing        | App\Http\Controllers\BrandsLandingController@index                     | |
|        | GET|HEAD | {brand}/email/resend           | verification.resend | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@resend                | web,auth,throttle:
|        | GET|HEAD | {brand}/email/verify           | verification.notice | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@show                  | web,auth                 |        | GET|HEAD | {brand}/email/verify/{id}      | verification.verify | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController@verify                | web,auth,signed,throttl|        | GET|HEAD | {brand}/login                  | login               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest                    |        | POST     | {brand}/login                  |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest                    |        | POST     | {brand}/logout                 | logout              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                          |        | POST     | {brand}/password/email         | password.email      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest                    |        | GET|HEAD | {brand}/password/reset         | password.request    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest                    |        | POST     | {brand}/password/reset         | password.update     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest                    |        | GET|HEAD | {brand}/password/reset/{token} | password.reset      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest                    |        | GET|HEAD | {brand}/register               | register            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest                    |        | POST     | {brand}/register               |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest
```

- Having no errors on the different routes.
- Can differentiate the routes name depending on the prefix like front1.login, front2.login, admin.login ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This error refers to the route() helper used in login.blade.php

Comment: Are you passing the `brand` to the route?

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add the code that is generating the url for `{brand}/login` in your `login.blade.php`

Comment: @Rwd  
`I can't edit it anymore : (`
`Sorry for the formatting.`

`Which code are you talking about ?`